# Choosing between LINQ, XSLT, or XQuery to process 2000 XML files

Tags: xml, linq, xslt, xquery

What is better suited to input 2000 XML files from disk and output a single XML file: XQuery, XSLT, or C# + LINQ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how you define "better", and what technologies are readily available to you. But typically, XSLT is better for transforming XML into different XML formats on disk; XQuery is better for more complex XML queries/applications and when the XML is in a database; LINQ is better when you're already in C# or VB, and you only need to execute basic queries over a relatively small amount of data. There are exceptions to everything, though, and it would be easier to make a recommendation with a more detailed example.

Based on your description, however, I would start with XSLT.